# Can the batch order of a pytorch data loader vary across devices, when shuffle=False?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory, dataloader

I'm instantiating a pytorch data loader with `shuffle=False` within a colab notebook (GPU runtime), like so:

`image_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)`

When I iterate through the data loader, the batch order is fixed within a given colab session (i.e. if I reinstantiate the data loader and then iterate through the data loader within different cells, the batch order matches):

`for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(image_data_loader): #…`

However, when I use different runtimes, the batch order often varies. I believe the variation may occur when the device type is different (e.g. a Tesla V100 versus P100, per `nvidia-smi`), but I haven't tested extensively enough to know whether it always comes down to device type.

I am using pytorch 1.9.0+cu102 and CUDA 11.2. Varying the random seed (`torch.manual_seed(random_seed)`, `torch.cuda.manual_seed(random_seed)`) does not change the batch order of the data loader on a given device -- suggesting that it is not possible to fix the order across devices using a random seed.

Can pytorch data loaders with `shuffle=False` indeed be instantiated with different batch orders? If so, is there a way to fix the batch order across devices?